# Redirect from login page when already logged in

Tags: laravel, authentication, redirect, laravel-5

I have a `laravel application` and i am learning it piece by piece. My question is the following:

Once a user logs in to the application using the Laravel Auth System, they are redirected to their respective dashboard. The problem is, when someone accidentally closes their browser, and they go to the website base url, it reloads the login page because we customized the authentication process

What I'd like to accomplish is if someone is logged in, if they go to the login page, which is actually `/` with a named route of `mylogin`, they get redirected to a different page.

Here's my attempt:

`RedirectIfAuthenticated Middleware:`

```
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        if($request->current()->getName()=='mylogin'){
            return redirect('/landlords/dashboard');
        }
        return redirect('/landlords/dashboard');
    }
```

Comment: They go to the login because the cokiee with the session id get deleted when they close the browser, so they have to relogin. You can read about remembering users in the laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#remembering-users

Comment: i added my attempt

Comment: I someone is logged in he can't go to the login page, is protected by a guard and is guest only

Comment: its a non guarded page though. this should be as easy as if page == login and authenticated redirect somewhere

Comment: In the Authorization system included in laravel you can't go to the login page if you are already authenticated. You can setup it with a command and a 10 minutes reading, no need to rewrite a new Auth system from scratch

Comment: yeh i understand this we have a custom login application thats using the laravel Auth system. everything is hooked up and implemented. i just need to know how to redirect somewhere else when a user goes to the / page and is authenticated

Comment: Please detail in your question that you are using a custom login system. you can always use that in your login controller constructor: `$this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');` this is taken from the laravel login controller

Comment: i did just detail that. let me try this

Comment: its already there

Comment: which type of customization ? i have done that things, would you please explain with more detail ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new middle ware where you can auth()->check and can easily redirect where you want.

Answer (score 0):

go to  `App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated` then change it from

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($this->auth->check()) {
        return redirect('/admin');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: this will redirect user to `/admin` and cannot go to another page

Comment: thats the url only ,you can change whatever

Comment: when will this middleware executed? in all route or just in login route?

Comment: how do i determine what page/route we are on? this will stop any page. or what baout what @RoyHabeahan said about this execution?